# Loading and processing very large files with java

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to load in a csv file with a huge amount of lines (>5 million) but it slows down massively when trying to process them all into an arraylist of each value

I've tried a few different variations of reading and removing from the input list i loaded from the file, but it still ends up running out of heapspace, even when i allocate 14gb to the process, while the file is only 2gb

I know i need to be removing values so that i dont end up with duplicate references in memory, so that I dont end up with an arraylist of lines and also an arraylist of the individual comma seperated values, but i have no idea how to do something like that

Edit : For reference, in this particular situation, data should end up containing 16 * 5 million values.

If there's a more elegant solution, i'm all for it

The intention when loading this file is to process it as a database, with the appropriate methods like select and select where, all handled by a sheet class. It worked just fine with my smaller sample file of 36k lines, but i guess it doesnt scale very well

Current code :

```
//Load method to load it from file

private static CSV loadCSV(String filename, boolean absolute)
{
    String fullname = "";
    if (!absolute)
    {
        fullname = baseDirectory + filename;
        if (!Load.exists(fullname,false))
            return null;
    }
    else if (absolute)
    {
        fullname = filename;
        if (!Load.exists(fullname,false))
            return null;
    }

    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fullname)))
    {
        stream.forEach(t -> {
            output.add(t);  
            atomicInteger.getAndIncrement();

            if (atomicInteger.get() % 10000 == 0)
            {
                Log.log("Lines done " + output.size());
            }

        });

        CSV c = new CSV(output);        

        return c;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.log("Error reading file " + fullname,3,"FileIO");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return null;

}


//Process method inside CSV class

public CSV(List<String> output)
{
    Log.log("Inside csv " + output.size());

    ListIterator<String> iterator = output.listIterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        ArrayList<String> d = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(iterator.next().split(splitter,-1)));
        data.add(d);
        iterator.remove();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to load the all file at once?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you mean when you talk about removing duplicate items?

Comment: I guess i dont need to, but I do later need the whole file's worth of lines loaded into memory when i start doing operations on it

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I mean that I want to avoid having an arraylist of lines and also an arraylist of each csv, meaning the whole thing is in memory effectively twice

Comment: If you dont have a problem with memory 
you can use `Files.readLine` to load it fast 
but it possibly will throw an exception of type OutOfMemory

Comment: It doesnt have a problem with loading the files, aside from slowing down towards the end, I included that there to show the way i was loading.
The big problem is splitting each line into individual values

Comment: It seems that you have code that doesn't work. Maybe instead you could start with a description of what you want to do with/to the CSV.

Comment: Give me a minute, i'll put that in @ShiDoiSi

Comment: I would have a method that took a line read from the file as parameter and split it into a list of strings and then returned that list. I would then add that list to the CSV object in the file reading loop. That would mean only one large collection instead of two and the read lines could be freed from memory quicker.

Comment: You could use an embedded database like [**H2**](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) and store every line there. Besides a RAM database you can use a file database.

Comment: I'll implement that and try that out  @JoakimDanielson

Comment: `if (!Load.exists(fullname,false))` is [a TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  "Check-then-do" is almost always a waste of time.  The "check" **isn't** the "do" so it's not going to accurately tell you if the "do" would work.  In this case:  the file could exist but you don't have permission to read it.  To quote a phrase:  just do it.  You have to handle all errors anyway, there's **no** check possible that can definitively tell you if the "do" will work, and even if there were things can change.

Comment: I'm just going to implement a cap on db sizes at 1m lines for now, it can quickly handle up to 2.5m but then it starts running out of memory
@JoakimDanielson if you submit that as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a method that took a line read from the file as parameter and split it into a list of strings and then returned that list. I would then add that list to the CSV object in the file reading loop. That would mean only one large collection instead of two and the read lines could be freed from memory quicker.
Something like this

```
CSV csv = new CSV();
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fullname))) {
    stream.forEach(t -> {
        List<String> splittedString = splitFileRow(t);
        csv.add(splittedString);  
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use any database, which provide required functionality for your task (select, group).
Any database can effective read and aggregate 5 million rows. 
Don't try to use "operations on ArrayList", it's works good only on small dataset.

Comment: The point is that i'm trying to build database functionality. If you have a better alternative to arraylist, or some pointers for a class to write that can dynamically increase in size like arraylist, tell me and i'll try that out

Comment: @duskfall In that case you want to study the implementation of databases, but that goes a little bit beyond SO, I'd say.

Comment: I've honestly not used them before, so i was working my way through learning sql while implementing the relevant functions into my sheet class

Comment: So, if you want to build your own database, in first you must read the file by parts with RandomAccessFile using seek() function, second you need to implements your own search indexes using self-implemented b-tree (or else) to know where in the file stored each row. And more and more ...

Answer (score 1):

I think some key concepts are missing here:

1. You said the file size is 2GB. That does not mean that when you load that file data in an `ArrayList`, the size in memory would also be 2GB. Why? Usually files store data using UTF-8 character encoding, whereas JVM internally stores `String` values using UTF-16. So, assuming your file contains only ASCII characters, each character occupies 1 byte in the filesystem whereas 2 bytes in memory. Assuming (for the sake of simplicity) all `String` values are unique, there will be space required to store the `String` references which are 32 bits each (assuming a 64 bits system with compressed oop). How much is your heap (excluding other memory areas)? How much is your eden space and old space? I'll come back to this again shortly.
2. In your code, you don't specify `ArrayList` size. This is a blunder in this case. Why? JVM creates a small `ArrayList`. After sometime JVM sees that this guy keeps pumping in data. Let's create a bigger `ArrayList` and copy the data of the old `ArrayList` into the new list. This event has some deeper implications when you are dealing with such huge volume of data: firstly, note that both the old and new arrays (with millions of entries) are in memory simultaneously occupying space, secondly unnecessarily data copy happens from one array to another - not once or twice but repeatedly, everytime the array run out of space. What happens to the old array? Well it's discarded and needs to be garbage collected. So, these repeated array copy and garbage collections slow down the process. CPU is really working hard here. What happens when your data no longer fits into the young generation (which is smaller than heap)? Maybe you need to see the behaviour using something like JVisualVM.

All in all, what I mean to say is there are good number of reasons why a 2GB file fills up your much larger heap and why your process performance is poor.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve this problem using pure Java it is overwhelming. I suggest using a processing engine like Apache Spark that can process the file in a distributed way, by increasing the level of parallelism.
Apache Spark has specific APIs to load CSV file:

```
spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("../Downloads/*.csv")
```

You can transform it into an RDD, or Dataframe and perform operations on it.
You can find more online, or [here](http://sparktutorials.net/Opening+CSV+Files+in+Apache+Spark+-+The+Spark+Data+Sources+API+and+Spark-CSV)